# Foreign Key Constraint Failing - Rails db migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, migration, model-associations

I have a 2 tables for my rails flight booker application - one for Flight and one for airports. I'm trying to pump in flight and airport data via seeding and keep getting a foreign key constraint error when seeding flight data below (rake db:seed). I tried playing around with the model associations but I'm not quite sure if that's the source of the problem.

Tables

```
Flight(id: integer, start_airport_id: integer, end_airport_id: integer, departure_time: datetime, flight_duration: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Airport(id: integer, airport_code: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Seed File

```
Airport.delete_all
airports = Airport.create([{ airport_code: 'SFO' }, { airport_code: 'NYC' }, { airport_code: 'LAX' }, 
{ airport_code: 'LAS' }, { airport_code: 'DEN' }, { airport_code: 'SEA' }, {airport_code: 'PHX' }])

Flight.delete_all
flights = Flight.create([{ start_airport_id: 1, end_airport_id: 2, departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 8, 29, 16, 30, 0), flight_duration: 5 }, 
{ start_airport_id: 1, end_airport_id: 3, departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 7, 13, 13, 0, 0), flight_duration: 2 }, 
{ start_airport_id: 1, end_airport_id: 4, departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 9, 7, 9, 30, 0), flight_duration: 2 }, 
{ start_airport_id: 2, end_airport_id: 7, departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 10, 6, 10, 0, 0), flight_duration: 5 }, 
{ start_airport_id: 1, end_airport_id: 2, departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 12, 4, 6, 30, 0), flight_duration: 6 }, 
{ start_airport_id: 3, end_airport_id: 2, departure_time: DateTime.new(2020, 11, 4, 11, 0, 0), flight_duration: 6 }])
```

Models

```
class Airport < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :departing_flights, class_name: "Flight"
    has_many :arriving_flights, class_name: "Flight"
end

class Flight < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :to_airport, foreign_key: :end_airport_id, class_name: "Airport"
    has_many :from_airport, foreign_key: :start_airport_id, class_name: "Airport"
end
```

Comment: You're getting complaints about `start_airport_id` and `end_airport_id`? Are you sure you have an airport with an `id` of `1`? If you had some airports before you call `Airport.delete_all` then new airports won't necessarily be created starting at `id=1`. So either you have to reset some sequences in the database or, when creating flights, look up the airports using their codes rather than assuming that you know what the `id`s are.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks! you're right - I thought I did have airports with the ID's I had inputted but I reloaded my rails console and saw that they started at a later sequence so I just had to reset the sequences. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Calling Airport.delete_all after running `rake db:seed` deleted all my instances of airports and created new ones but different id's. I had to reset some sequences in the db like @muistooshort suggested using the active-record-reset-pk-sequence gem here [https://github.com/splendeo/activerecord-reset-pk-sequence] . Below `Airport.delete_all`  I added `Airport.reset_pk_sequence` after installing the gem and it worked!